# How to check how many people are using the database right now, that is, how to check online?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**How to check how many people are using the database right now, that is, how to check online?**

I tried to create a separate path with an online number, after which if the user entered the activity this number is added by 1, if it exits (onDestroy) it is subtracted by 1. This works a little, but it works inefficiently and with bugs that I don't need.

How can I do this?

I need something like this, it doesn't work of course, but I want to give an example:

```
              DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/online");
                        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                Long numberOfUsers = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                                online = findViewById(R.id.online);

                                online.setText("Online: " + numberOfUsers);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                                System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Are you looking for a Presence system? If yes, see https://firebase.blog/posts/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I need java and I want to check how many people are currently using the application, that is, they are online

Comment: You can adapt the JavaScript code from the article to Java/A,ndroid: the SDKs are similar.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec The fact is that I'm not looking for what you sent